# Fulltext search doesn't exclude -xxxword

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

We use fulltext search on a french CMS ( SPIP ). The resultat of a search with a minus word doesn't seems correct. We tried the sql request generated by the CMS in phpMyAdmin :

```
SELECT t.id_zotspip, t.titre, t.resume, 
    MATCH(t.`titre`) AGAINST ('+corrosion    -bacteria' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 10 
    + MATCH(t.`titre`,t.`resume`) AGAINST ('+corrosion -bacteria' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 2.2 AS score 
FROM `spip_zotero311`.spip_zitems AS t 
WHERE ((MATCH(t.`titre`) AGAINST ('+corrosion -bacteria' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
     OR (MATCH(t.`titre`,t.`resume`) AGAINST ('+corrosion -bacteria' IN BOOLEAN MODE))) 
GROUP BY t.id_zotspip ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 0,500
```

We get results with bacteria in the resume...

The type of the table is MyISAM but the type of the base is InnoDB.

Any suggestions ?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you use `GROUP BY t.id_zotspip`? It seems incorrect.

Comment: Also I think you should replace `OR` inside `WHERE` clause with `AND`.

Comment: Thank you ! When the OR is replace with a AND in the clause WHERE, the result seems ok ! Now we have to figure out why SPIP generate a wrong request... Thank you again for your help !

Comment: Oups ! It's doesn't work so well... Now, fulltext search works only on the Title. The items with corrosion only in the resume are not found...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `OR` clause inside `where`. You should replace `OR` inside `WHERE` clause with `AND`.

Comment: Like I said earlier... It's doesn't work so well... Now, fulltext search works only on the Title. The items with corrosion only in the resume are not found... We are still looking for  some help witht that...